# Do they sound natural? or make sense?

Tags: ellipses

Please read the following sentences and tell me if they sound natural or make sense.

a.  John talks Mary into stduying French more often than Sue into studying English.

b. John forced Jack into buying the house and Mary Max into believing that news.

c. John will forc Jack into buying the house and Mary will Max into believing that news.

Many thanks!

Comment: Aside from the minor typos / spelling errors, yes, they're perfectly comprehensible, but no, they're not at all natural. They sound much more like something you'd read in an English primer (for beginning students) or in reading comprehension / word problems.  That said, this is not the kind of question we can answer formally on this site (see the [help/on-topic]), so we'll have to close it, unless you can ask more specific questions about particular constructions or points of usage you have questions about (and have done some prior reading or research on).

Comment: ... I'd say the deletion in c (of base-form after modal) takes us over onto the ungrammatical side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a  is comprehensible, b and c are very convoluted and difficult to understand.  what are you trying to say?

Comment: Answers should not contain questions. You have earned the privilege of commenting: you should use it.

Comment: The first sentence was supposed to be an answer to the question, the last for further help if required (i.e. how to improve the sentences).  Surely if the question is about comprehensibility then the fact that it's not possible to understand a sentence is an answer in itself?

Comment: If your answer needs to request additional clarification from the OP, then the question is not in the proper shape to receive answers. If your answer is essentially nothing more than "yes" or "no", and has no supporting justification, citations, arguments, etc, then it should be a comment, not an answer. At a higher level: questions like this are off-topic on the site (you can see it's been closed now, and was sitting at -1 a long time before that), and we prefer not to encourage them by posting answers.

Comment: fair, I'm pretty new here so thanks for the clarification